# CSS transform rotate align top of parent w/ dynamic width

Tags: css, css-transforms

Example: http://mattharris.org/index2.html

Everything is fine until I start messing w/ moving things. Example click any of the 3 bottom divs and you will see the text move incorrectly.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1 class="title">MattHarris dot Com</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="sepbar"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="vertical-text">Skills</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="vertical-text">Resume</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="vertical-text">Contact</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sepbar"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    font-size: 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.vertical-text {
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 4%;
}

.box:hover {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.box:nth-child(1) { background-color: #9dc9d2; }

.box:nth-child(2) { background-color: #a8cfd7; }

.box:nth-child(3) { background-color: #b3d5dc; }
```

**JS:**

```
$(".box").click(function() {
    var link = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    link = link.replace(/^\s+/, '');
    link = link.replace(/\s+$/, '');
    switch(link) {
        case "skills":
            $(".box:nth-child(1)").animate({width:"92%"});
            $(".box:nth-child(2)").animate({width:"4%"});
            $(".box:nth-child(3)").animate({width:"4%"});
            break;
        case "resume":
            $(".box:nth-child(1)").animate({width:"4%"});
            $(".box:nth-child(2)").animate({width:"92%"});
            $(".box:nth-child(3)").animate({width:"4%"});
            break;
        case "contact":
            $(".box:nth-child(1)").animate({width:"4%"});
            $(".box:nth-child(2)").animate({width:"4%"});
            $(".box:nth-child(3)").animate({width:"92%"});
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: You should include the relevant code in the question itself. It makes helping you a lot easier in addition to the problem no longer appearing in the question after it has been fixed

Comment: sure thing editing....

Comment: @morissette where do you want the text to be? Halfway out of the box or completely contained within the box?

Comment: No, I would like the text to be w/in the box w/ minimum padding and stay that location on the change of width of the parent div

Comment: @Dennis to expand - top left

Comment: It is difficult to trouble shoot this error without seeing the code that is causing it. Try making a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the error. The code you have isn't sufficient.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NQ8a5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that rotating elements rotate about their center. When the width of the element changes, the center moves and this changes the point of rotation.

If you give your elements a fixed width, rather than a percentage, this problem won't arise.

Here's a fiddle, the key part is:

```
.vertical-text {
    width: 30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/John_C/tE5Ht/

Here's the solution applied to your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/John_C/NQ8a5/1/

Comment: Thank you. I should not have had to bounty something with such a simple solution. I appreciate your explanation and will awary you said bounty when possible.

Comment: Thanks, problems like these can be frustrating if you don't know their cause!

Answer (score 4):

There's another way, which takes the rotate transform function logically better into account.

[`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) lets you modify the origin for transformations of an element. The `transform-origin` of the `rotate()` function is by default the centre of rotation.

So you could put the origin at left bottom with `transform-origin: 0 100% 0;`. Values are X, Y and Z coordinates. In this solution you also need to set a `height` and similar negative `margin-left` (which with through transform has to be margin-top).

CSS excerpt:

```
.vertical-text {
    height: 2.2rem;
    margin-top: -2.2rem;
    -webkit-transform: rotate( 90deg );
       -moz-transform: rotate( 90deg );
        -ms-transform: rotate( 90deg );
         -o-transform: rotate( 90deg );
            transform: rotate( 90deg );
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100% 0;
       -moz-transform-origin: 0 100% 0;
        -ms-transform-origin: 0 100% 0;
         -o-transform-origin: 0 100% 0;
            transform-origin: 0 100% 0;
    line-height: 2.2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

And **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Volker_E/5Ja3Q/)**.

I've also added line-height to make the text vertically centered in the box and set the length value to `rem`, but you can use pixels or ems like you wish.

This solution might seem a bit more complicated than setting just the `width`, but you don't have to care about text length at all and have *dynamic width on all boxes*.